# Media Element set auto heigth and width

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I have media element problem. There are black areas in the controll, and since my background in application is white id does not look good. I know that there is no way to chage the color (or maybe I am wrong), but maybe there is a way to achieve this with xaml.

[image]
[image]

The first picture is what I currenly have (orange color is video). And the second picture show what I want to achieve.

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"> 
    <MediaElement x:Name="CameraFeed" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
</Grid>
```

Above is my xaml code - the greed needs to be streched since it is in pivot and I want the entire pivot to be draggable. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after some tests I managed to do it. I' am posting anwere in case anyone has similar problem:

Initialy my MediaElement has Visibility property set to Collapsed, so I need to add MediaElement_Started event.

In this event after I change visibility I call this function:

```
    public void SetMinimizedImage()
    {
        var naturalWidth = CameraFeed.NaturalVideoWidth;
        var naturalHeigth = CameraFeed.NaturalVideoHeight;
        var width = CameraGrid.ActualWidth;
        var heigth = CameraGrid.ActualHeight;

        if(naturalWidth < width)
        {
            CameraFeed.Height = naturalHeigth;
            CameraFeed.Width = naturalWidth;
            return;
        }

        var ratio = naturalWidth / width;
        var heigthToSet = heigth / ratio;
        CameraFeed.Height = heigthToSet;
        CameraFeed.Width = width;
    }
```

And It sets desired heigth and width witout black area. :) If you have any improvments to this code go ahead and tell me!